# Is there any App to share android device screen?

Tags: mobile, android

We have to give a demo to our team for one of our Android Application. I was searching for an app like AirPlay that will share the screen of my Android device on the HDTV and team will be able to view it.

But all I came across the apps that can share files, videos, photos on the screen but not the device screen. (http://www.knowyourmobile.com/android-apps/18049/best-airplay-apps-android-gettin-dream-stream)

I came across one app called mirror (http://www.engadget.com/2013/12/12/mirror-android-beta-airplay-mirroring/), but its not present on Google Play.

SO if anybody has any idea about such application, please share.

Comment: You might try asking http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not clear to me what this has to do with QA/Test.

Answer (score 1):

If you have kitkat you can use **Miracast**, see Wi-Fi CERTIFIED Miracast section https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html

see also this video [on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v93CfAHO_7k](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v93CfAHO_7k)

Comment: Hey Onivas,
Thanks a lot for this information. It's really helpful.

Comment: The Mircast feature in Android is related and limited to KitKat only (that's what I learned from the URL https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html).

While exploring the web I came across one more tool called as "AndroidScreenCapure" which I installed and successfully showed demo using same. You can find more details about installation of this application from below URL:

http://www.mightypocket.com/2010/09/installing-android-screenshots-screen-capture-screen-cast-for-windows/

Comment: Yes, Miracast is only available for kitkat devices, I wrote it in the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool [Mobizen](https://www.mobizen.com/?locale=en)

You will need to download it's companion mirorring app from the play store

it easily allows to share android screen and you don't need to root your device also

It has good manual and easy installation and you can get goining in less than 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

if you want it working on all Platforms you should use [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm). It's an Addon for Chrome Webbrowser. 
The free version can also be installed manually without chrome from the website: [Download page](https://www.vysor.io/download/?return=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vysor.io%2F)

1. Download
2. Install
3. Connect Device via USB
4. Run (vysor installs a APK on your device via adb)

The free version displays advertising on startup and every 15 minutes. There is a purchasable version aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Most devices will support a [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) server, for android see: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=vnc%20server&c=apps

You must root the device, so the server can get access to the display.

With [a VNC viewer](https://www.google.com/search?q=vnc%20viewer) you can connect to it with a laptop or another device that supports the viewer. You can also control the device from the VNC viewer, with a mouse and keyboard. Connect the laptop to the HDTV device and your done.

You can also run automated tests against a VNC server with [the T-Plan Robot](http://www.t-plan.com/robot/) (Commercial version) or [the Open Source variant](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplanrobot/)